# Oracle date issue with query

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Using Oracle 12c database. The following fields are set as Date for the datatype in the database.

The following query either shows dates that are not in the database or throws the Ora 0092 error. I think I'm trying to format it incorrectly?

```
daysFromNow = GetConstant("VWSTD_REAG_DATE_RANGE", USER)
today = Date() 
checkDate = DateAdd(Date(), daysFromNow) 

fldStr = "NAME, ACTIVE, EXPIRATION_DATE, SAMPLE_NUMBER, TEMPLATE"

qry =       " select {fldStr} {cr}" 
qry = qry & " from STANDARD_REAGENT {cr}"
qry = qry & " where EXPIRATION_DATE <= {checkDate} {cr}"
qry = qry & " order by EXPIRATION_DATE, TEMPLATE, NAME "
```

The above code runs in a subroutine so the first 4 lines are handled correctly.
`EXPIRATION_DATE` and `checkDate` are both showing as date data types.
The `{}` indicate a context translate function that is also being handled correctly. This subroutine is running in a basic session that is within a Smalltalk application.

I can copy the query once it is translated and run in in Oracle Developer with the same results.

Comment: 1) that ORA-00092 seems to be a DB User related error, not a SW/Query error, 2) I really hope this software isn't doing string replacement for `{tag}` (Bobby Tables) 3) if it is, you best wrap that `{checkDate}` in a `TO_DATE()`

Comment: what programming language are you using here? what is the meaning of error  "Ora 009"?

Comment: if the translated query throws the same error in the Oracle Developer then put it in the Oracle Developer, remove as much as possible from the query such that the error is still thrown and then post the reduced query  and the error message here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `checkDate = DateAdd(today, daysFromNow)`?